# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

I have a video on a screen that must be played with an infinity loop.

So I wrote :

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avItem];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[_player currentItem]];

[_player play];
```

And I fallback method is :

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [_player.currentItem seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [_player play];
}
```

It works well but sometimes it seems that my fallback is not called. The video is freezing at the end and never played again. It's happening randomly ...

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Could you try without setting the object on notification observer if that works.

Comment: I think the problem is that "currentItem is set asynchronously, so we must KVO that property and after that observe the AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"

Comment: You need to add the observer AFTER starting play.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set a boundary time observer.

```
    - (id) setupBoundaryEndWith:(NSArray*)array
    {
        __weak MY_AVPlayer* weakself = self;
        return [self addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:array queue:NULL usingBlock:^{
            [weakself stopAVPlayerAndLoopOrTriggerNextTrack];
            }];
    }
```

Comment: I setup the array containing one CMTime, which is the duration, but sometime it works, sometime it does not

Comment: @onmyway133 - could it be that you have not set your CMTimeScale to something fine enough - I use 60000. You could also set your boundary observer for say a hundredth of a second before the actual end of the track to be sure it's hit.

Answer (score 2):

`[_player currentItem]` is  `null`, since you haven't started playing yet. I would suggest either to explicitly add the `AVPlayerItem` (ideally) or register to notifications after starting the playback (reverse the 2 last lines).

I have not tried the 2-nd solution, so it might not work, if it takes some time to start the playback. If that is the case, I suggest setting an `NSTimer` to trigger a second later and then register.